# Selling my broken Macbook. How to make sure there's no personal information on the hard drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, security, privacy

My Mac won't turn on but I'd like to sell it for spare parts. How can I make sure there's no personal information stored on the hard drive for the buyer to retrieve?

Comment: You could try booting it in Target Mode and then erase the disk from another machine. But that assumes it does at least turn on...

Comment: Sell it without the hard drive?

Comment: What @Ashley said.  If you want to sell it with the drive, you could try connecting the drive to another machine temporarily.  On the other hand, if you used FileVault 2, you may not have to worry at all—just don't supply your password.

Comment: Does "won't turn on" mean it doesn't power up, or doesn't boot, or...?

Comment: → Ashley: good point. And if the disk is the failure point bend it with pliers at the central axe level.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what model it is, if it has an Optical drive then you can insert the install disc that came with the machine and boot to the disc where you can use Disk utility to erase the drive.

Comment: Dany's Mac doesn't turn on ☹! Its performance with the DVD reader will be off too.

Comment: Open up the machine and remove the hard drive

Answer (score 1):

If the hard drive is OK and
one of the spare parts to sell,
then you will have

1. to extract this disk from the MacBook,
2. install it within another one and
3. format it with DU + `Security Options…` = `Zero Out Data` (which is
   the right one for the risk you want to cover).